# Showing openess in topology of point-wise convergence

Tags: general-topology

I want to check if the set

$$ P_{x_0}=\{f\in C([a,b])\mid f(x_0)=0\},\quad x_0\in[a,b] $$

is open in the topology of point-wise convergence.

I already have a problem with an intuitive picture of this topology. I know it is has the basis

$$ O(x_1,\ldots,x_n,t_1,\ldots,t_n,\varepsilon)=\{f\in C([a,b])\mid f(x_i)\in B_\varepsilon(t_i),\quad i=1,\ldots,n\}. $$

If I had to guess I would say $P_{x_0}$ is not open because the property in $O$ only needs a finite number of points, so I think there's a way to construct a function which lies in $O$ but has a non-zero "spike" at $x_0$.

Is my approach correct or am I wrong with the way I imagine this basis set?

Comment: Notice that projection is continuous, so the set $P_{x_0}$ is in fact closed. Well in general that does not prevent it to be open. So, it is easier to prove that the complement is not closed. Can you think of a sequence $f_n$ with $f_n(x_0)\ne 0$ which converges to a $f$ with $f(x_0)=0$?

Comment: Your base is correct. But there are many ways to view the topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P_{x_0}$ is **not** open in $C([a,b])$, but it *is* closed, as it equals $e_{x_0}^{-1}[\{0\}]$ where $e_p: C([a,b]) \to \Bbb R$ is the evaluation map $e_p(f)=f(p)$ for any $p \in [a,b]$.

The point-wise convergence topology is the minimal topology that makes all $e_p$ continuous, by definition. And the inverse of a closed set under a continuous map is closed.

To see it $P_{x_0}$ is not open, note that $c_{\frac{1}{n}}$ (the constant map with value $\frac1n$), defines a sequence not in $P_{x_0}$ that converges point-wise to $c_0$ (the zero function) that *is* in the set. So $c_0$ is not an interior point of $P_{x_0}$.